# Laptop screen turn blank after windows 8 boot logo

Tags: windows-8, laptop, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I recently installed Windows 8 on a Dell Inspiron (N5110) laptop which had been previously running Windows 7 Ultimate. After the installation the laptop restarted, displaying the windows 8 logo followed by a black screen.

After several attempts at powering it on and off with the same results I decided to connect an external monitor (SONY TV) via a HDMI cable, which worked just fine; I was able to create my  account and log into the computer.

I checked on settings (Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution) and realized the computer only detected the external display.

Later i found out that when booted in Safe Mode, My pc display works just fine. Right now i am using a HP monitor for work. Is there any way I can resolve this So that I am able to use my mobile PC display? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it right at last, The problem is a bios issue for dell computers(some). I fixed it by flashing(updating) the bios using a tool i found on the dell support page. Everything is fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a driver issue of some sort. I know it's only a basic answer but have you tried downloading up to date drivers from the Dell website? It's strange that an external monitor works because it indicates it's unlikely to be a video card driver issue as such...

Comment: Thanks for the rreply. I downloaded and installed intel drivers (Intel HD Graphics 3000 Driver) from the Dell website but that hasn't helped.

Comment: Hmm, try booting into safe mode again, type 'Device Manager' on the Start screen and choose the option. When the snap-in window opens, expand the display adaptors category, right-click your display device and choose Uninstall. Reboot and try in standard boot mode. If it works, try redownloading and installing latest drivers. This has worked before when I've had this issue.

Comment: If it doesn't achieve anything, also try following that same process but instead of choosing 'Uninstall', choose 'Disable' then reboot again.

Comment: I managed to get it right at last, The problem is a bios issue for dell computers(some). I fixed it by flashing(updating) the bios using a tool i found on the dell support page. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Wow.. that's so strange but I'm glad it solved the problem!